# Rails 7/Stimulus: Connect() fires twice but why can I only access values on its first firing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I understand that `connect()` will fire twice in Rails due to Turbo first loading a cached version of the page.

I have a form model. Within the model I have embedded a Stripe card element.

I am trying to mount that element in `connect()`

```
<%= form_with model: @booking, data: { controller: :booking, action: 'booking#submit:prevent', 'booking-stripekey-value' => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:public_key], booking_formauth_value: form_authenticity_token } do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :tour_id, value: @booking.tour.id, data: { booking_target: :tour } %>

  <%= form.email_field :email, data: { booking_target: :email} %>

  <div id="card" data-booking-target="card" name= "booking[card]"></div>

  <%= form.submit "Book now" %>
<% end %>
```

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  
  static values = {
    stripekey: String,
    formauth: String
  }

  static targets = ['form']

  connect() {
    let key = this.stripekeyValue

    let stripe = Stripe(key)
    let elements = stripe.elements()
    let cardElement = elements.create('card')
    cardElement.mount('#card')
  }

  submit(e) {
    console.log('Submit!')
  }
}
```

When `connect()` fires the first time the value of `key` is set to the Stripe api key. However, when `connect()` fires again, `key` has no value. `this` appears to be something different the second time around.

Is there a way to ensure `connect()` fires only the first time? If not, how can I ensure the correct value is set on the second time?